# Смердящая смерть

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Разлагающийся труп, как известно, распространяет вокруг себя тошнотворный запах. Часто упоминающаяся в русских сказках речка Смородина является символом рубежа между миром мёртвых и миром живых.

Внимание - вопрос: не являются ли однокоренными слова *смерть* и *смердеть*? А если да, то, может быть, *смерд* означает *простой смертный*? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

В современнном языке нет. Если говорить об этимологии, то ярый исследователь дохристианской Руси, академик Б. А. Рыбаков, действительно связывал смерть (буквально "хорошая смерть") и смердов. По его мнению, еще у праславян был обычай "соумирания", когда вместе с князем в могилу шли еще его подопечные, причем именно из числа славян. Эти соумирающие, по Рыбакову, и назывались "смерды".

Правда, нужно учитывать, что изыскания Рыбакова далеко не всегда соответствуют принципу научности, и нередко фантазия в них превалирует над фактами.

Более обоснованной выглядит версия, что "смерд" от "смердеть" - плохо пахнуть. В Древней Руси в основном использовалась подсечно-огневая система земледелия, при которой пашню устраивали на месте огневища, расчищенного огнем от растительности участка, в результате чего, обильно удобренная золой земля давала солидный урожай. Естественно от такого крестьянина пепелищем несло за версту, из-за чего они и могли получить свое наименование.

Comment: Версия Б.А. Рыбакова представляется мне более достоверной.

Запах дыма, золы  вовсе не смердящий. Он может казаться таковым только современному городскому жителю, принюхавшемуся с к выхлопам автомобилей.

Comment: Ягода (и река) смородина названа так не за неприятный, а за сильный запах. Любой слишком сильный запах неприятен. Смерть тоже весьма "пахуча"... Чую я тут какой-то скрытый смысл, какую-то глубину...

Comment: Есть такой вариант: герой преодолевает неприятное воздействие как личностей нехороших - Ка́лин (обосранный)Царь - так и окружающей среды: река Смородина (вонючка), Ка́линов мост (т.е. мост, принадлежащий царю Ка́лину; хотя по остальным ТТХ мост может быть вполне нормальным - просто пограничным). И герой с этим справляется...  ;)

Comment: Tom d_Cat, знаете, если провести йоговскую процедуру, которая называется шанк-пракшалана (очистка пищеварительного тракта), то и мысли значительно прояснятся. Вот попробуйте.

Comment: Если полагаете, что этот вариант изблевал я, то ошибаетесь. Я лишь отобрал микродозу и представил для анализа уважаемому сообществу.

Answer (score 1):

Смердеть - плохо  пахнуть  -  это  современное  значение.  Раньше,  возможно,  просто   пахнуть.  Привязывать  слово  к  запаху  дыма  и  гари  -  натяжка.  Есть  и  другие  нехорошие  запахи.  У  слова  смерть  индоевропейские  корни,  и  значение  ясное.  А  о  значении  слова  смерд  историки  ещё  спорят.  И  созвучие  в  корнях  может  оказаться  просто  созвучием.                                                           Не  вдаваясь  в  тонкости   лингвистического  анализа,  хочу  заметить,  что  словосочетание  "смердящая  смерть"  и  даже  сближение  этих  понятий   может  появиться   только  в  атеистическом  сознании.  В  любых  религиях  смерть  это  чрезвычайно  важный  этап  бытия,  как  и рождение.   Связь (родственная)  слова  смерд   с  словом   смердеть   сомнительна,  т.к.   основная   часть   древнерусского   общества   не  может  официально  ( в  правовых  документах )  именоваться  фактически  ругательством.

Comment: Действительно, историкам доподлинно неизвестно, кто такой "смерд", но если слово произошло от "смердеть", то особым запахом мог быть или пот, или гарь. Так как холопы, закупы и пр., тоже потели, остаётся только гарь.

Comment: Гарь  это  явление  временное.  Они  же  не  углежоги  всё-таки.  Да  и,  поджигая  лес,  люди  в  нём  не  сидели.

Comment: >Да и, поджигая лес, люди в нём не сидели

Как раз-таки сидели. Суть подсечно-огневой системы в том, что сгоревшие растения удобряют почву, и покуда они её удобряют урожай хороший. Запах гари в сгоревшем лесу стоит очень долго, а тут осевшую золу ещё и постоянно поднимали пахотой.

Comment: Наверное всё же "смердеть" - это именно "плохо (слишком сильно) пахнуть". Просто "пахнуть" - "вонять", иначе не возникло бы слово "благовоние". По-польски "духи" - "вонявки".

Но смотрите: смЕрдеть - смЕрть; смОрод - мОр... а от мора недалеко до мороза, который может быть причиной смерти... мрАзь - смрАд...
Случайны ли эти созвучия?

Comment: Я  нашёл, что  первый  сев  производился  без  пахоты.  Но  сие  не  так  важно.  Я  не  знаю  какой  запах  стоит  в  избе,  которая  топится  по  чёрному.  Думаю  дымок  преобладает.  А  это  почаще,  чем  временная  работа  на  гарях.  От  живности,  которая  зимой  могла  содержаться  в  избе,  тоже  дух  бывает.  Правда  к  запаху  привыкаешь.  Князья  и  бояре  чувствовали  конечно - у  них  были  другие  бытовые  условия.  Но  запах  гари,  как  повод  для  называния  самого  многочисленного  социального  слоя - натяжка.  А  как  они  сами  себя  называли ?

Comment: Действительно,  положительного  значения  за  словом  "смердеть"  не  прослеживается,  разве  что  ягода - смородина.  Слова ( корни )  мнгозначимы,  значения  могут  разойтись  до  наоборот.  Но  и  омонимы  тоже  имеют  место  быть.  Случайны  или  не  случайны  созвучия  сразу  не  скажешь.  А  что  исследований  на  эту  тему  нет ?

Comment: Есть, но такое... пунктирное. Больше вопросов, чем ответов.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что натяжка. Древесный дым производит антисептическое действие, в чёрных избах была здоровая атмосфера.

Третье сословие называлось кресьяне (от "кресало" - "огниво")или крестьяне (главный арийский символ - свастический крест - связан со стихией огня). Хозяев дома (дыма, очага) называли "огнищане".

Comment: По-французски "кал" звучит как "мерд", сМЕРДит потому что, ага. Во французском это (как и многие другие) слово никак не этимологизируется.

Comment: Французское  "мерд"  прямой  потомок  латинского  "мерда"(merda)  c  тем  же  значением.  Куст  слов  с  этим  значением  делится  на  слова  с  начальным  "с"  -  это  славянские  ( смердеть )  и  без  начального  "с" - неславянские.  Два  неславянских  вы  уже  знаете.  Источник  -  индоевропейский  язык.   Латынь  наиболее  близка  к  славянским.  В  других  индоевропейских  значения  разбегаются  сильнее.

Comment: Третье  сословие (податное )  -  это  из  европейского  политлексикона.  Крестьяне  слово  довольно  позднее  -  переозвученное  христиане.  И  если  крест  и  участвует  в  этимологии,  то  это  крест -  христианский.  Огнищанин  в  Киевской  Руси  -  высший  чин  княжеской  администрации.  Есть  и  другие  значения,  но  человек  это  высокопоставленный,  хотя  и  не  свободный  (  княжий  холоп ).

Comment: Насчёт  происхождения  слова  "смерд"  нашёл  интересное  сообщение  у  Фасмера,  о  том,  что  он  отрицает  происхождение  этого  слова   от  персидского  "мерд" (  человек )  по  грамматическим  основаниям.  Интересно,  что  есть  учёные,  такую  версию  выдвигающие.  По  историческим,  лексикологическим  и  психологическим  основаниям  она  вполне  подходит.

Comment: bernard прав . Созвучие слов  ещё не результат общего их происхождения . И для слов СМЕРТЬ , СМЕРД , СМЕРДЕТЬ  общая связь    суть не факт . А у жихарки каша в голове .

Answer (score 0):

У наших предков отношения со смертью были довольно непринуждённые: солдаты из крестьян на поле боя легко брали чужие жизни и легко отдавали свою, крестьянки спокойно относились к потере младенца - "к житью - дак выживет", "Бог дал, бог взял".

УдМУРТы, МОРДва, МАРийцы, МЕРя - это, как написал Mado, означает просто *люди*(а bernard добавил, что, оказывается, ещё и по-персидски "мерд" - "человек"). Живущие согласно принципу "Memento MORi!" ("Помни о смерти!")

Значит, словообразование шло так. Центральным понятием является *смерть* (корень -МР(Т/Д)-).
В одну сторону от него отпочковывается *смерд* со значением *простой смертный*, в другую - *смород, смрад, смердеть* (ведь смердит обычно то, что умерло и разлагается).

Не знаю, как у кого, но у меня лично картинка сложилась. Спасибо за помощь всем, кто уделил внимание рассмотрению этого вопроса.)))

Comment: Картинка  стройная.  Академик  Б. Рыбаков  тоже  считает  также.  Но  у  него  это  всё  называется  гипотезой.

Comment: Про меря и марийцев я не писал